# PHP Sessions with cookies (lifetime and files)

Tags: php, session, cookies, web-hosting

I have followed a tutorial to work with sessions using cookies. I have now two issues:

1. My lifetime session is too short (one or two hours), eventhough I've set the value of `session.cookie_lifetime` and `session.gc_maxlifetime` to "1209600"
2. I try to save sessions into files using:

   ```
   ini_set("session.save_handler", "files");
   session_set_save_handler($session, true);
   session_save_path($rel_path . "/sessions");
   ```

   where `$session` is the instance of the sessions I've created but not yet started.

Now, this works correctly when I use it locally with XAMPP, but not when I upload the site online. I guess the problem comes from my web host which is www.ovh.com, but I have no idea on how to solve this problem. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: check phpinfo(). it'll show the master (hardcoded .ini/php_value settings), and the current "local" setting, which is the end-result of all the .ini/php_value + ini_set() overrides. you may be setting the value in one place, but that doesn't mean it can't be overridden elsewhere.

Comment: If it works at the local system, then maybe modifying configs on the live system would help?

Comment: @MarcB the "Local Value" is correctly "updated" when I check the `phpinfo()`, while the "Master Value" is displayed as default.

Comment: @bub what kind of modification would you suggest?

Comment: I am not sure about the concrete modification, but the fact is that your code works on the local system and it does'nt  work  when its "online". So there must be a difference between the configuration of the systems. Maybe you contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding this line of code:

```
ini_set('session.force_path', 0);
```

with the other `ini_set` and `session` parameters. The `session.force_path` parameter wasn't visible in the **session** section when I printed the phpinfo() locally (using **XAMPP**), while it was on my web hosting service. This also solved my session lifetime issue as it was depending on the existence of the session file.